# Can't Connect to WMI Provider on New SQL 2022 Install

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2022

I have a fresh installation of Microsoft SQL Server 2022 on Windows Server 2022 Standard. I'm attempting to enable Always On Availability Groups with [the `Enable-SqlAlwaysOn` PowerShell commandlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/enable-sqlalwayson?view=sqlserver-ps) but it fails with "An attempt to connect to WMI on 'COMPUTERNAME' failed with the following error: SQL Server WMI provider is not available on COMPUTERNAME..".

In the past I've run into WMI issues after in-place OS upgrades however this is a new server and no other versions of SQL Server have ever been installed on it. SQL Server 2022 Configuration Manager launches without issue. Running `mofcomp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Shared\sqlmgmprovider.mof"` hasn't fixed the issue. My account is part of `sysadmin` and I've verified I can connect to the instance.

This is something I'd expect to work out of the box and I'm not sure what to troubleshoot or try next.

The class-names are identical between and `computermanagement15` on 2019 and `computermanagement16` on 2022. This is the output of `Get-CimClass -Namespace "root\microsoft\sqlserver\computermanagement16" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CimClassName`

```
CIM_Indication
CIM_ClassIndication
CIM_ClassDeletion
CIM_ClassCreation
CIM_ClassModification
CIM_InstIndication
CIM_InstCreation
CIM_InstModification
CIM_InstDeletion
__NotifyStatus
__ExtendedStatus
CIM_Error
MSFT_WmiError
MSFT_ExtendedStatus
__SecurityRelatedClass
__Trustee
__NTLMUser9X
__ACE
__SecurityDescriptor
__PARAMETERS
__SystemClass
__ProviderRegistration
__EventProviderRegistration
__ObjectProviderRegistration
__ClassProviderRegistration
__InstanceProviderRegistration
__MethodProviderRegistration
__PropertyProviderRegistration
__EventConsumerProviderRegistration
__thisNAMESPACE
__NAMESPACE
__IndicationRelated
__FilterToConsumerBinding
__EventConsumer
__AggregateEvent
__TimerNextFiring
__EventFilter
__Event
__NamespaceOperationEvent
__NamespaceModificationEvent
__NamespaceDeletionEvent
__NamespaceCreationEvent
__ClassOperationEvent
__ClassDeletionEvent
__ClassModificationEvent
__ClassCreationEvent
__InstanceOperationEvent
__InstanceCreationEvent
__MethodInvocationEvent
__InstanceModificationEvent
__InstanceDeletionEvent
__TimerEvent
__ExtrinsicEvent
__SystemEvent
__EventDroppedEvent
__EventQueueOverflowEvent
__QOSFailureEvent
__ConsumerFailureEvent
__EventGenerator
__TimerInstruction
__AbsoluteTimerInstruction
__IntervalTimerInstruction
__Provider
__Win32Provider
__SystemSecurity
ClientSettings
ServerSettingsExtendedProtection
SqlErrorLogEvent
ClientNetworkProtocol
ServerNetworkProtocol
SqlServerAlias
ServerNetworkProtocolProperty
ServerSettings
HADRServiceSettings
SqlServiceAdvancedProperty
SecurityCertificate
ClientSettingsGeneralFlag
ClientNetLibInfo
ServerNetworkProtocolIPAddress
SqlService
RegServices
ClientNetworkProtocolProperty
ServerSettingsGeneralFlag
FilestreamSettings
SqlErrorLogFile
```

Comment: Check the firewalls

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher the firewall's open. This command is running on the local server that's hosting the database too. I've done the same thing with 2019 installs without issue so a bit stumped here.

Comment: Are you running it locally or remotely? Have you verified the namespaces exist?

Comment: @SeanGallardy, re-approaching this now that I've returned from holidays. I'm getting the same results through WinRM and PowerShell as admin on the server. I've verified `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement` both exist version `16.0.0.0` compared to `15.0.0.0` for 2019 installs. `New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer'` doesn't populate `Services`, `ClientProtocols`, `ServerInstances`, nor `ServerAliases` but does for 2019 which I think is related.

Comment: Did you look at the actual WMI namespace to see if it exists?

Comment: @SeanGallardy how would I do that and what would I be looking for?

Comment: Get-WmiObject -Class __namespace -Namespace "root\microsoft\sqlserver" | where Name -eq "ComputerManagement16"

If that comes back with data then the namespace exists.

Comment: If the namespace exists, list the classes: Get-CimClass -Namespace "root\microsoft\sqlserver\computermanagement16"

Comment: @SeanGallardy they exist, I've added the output to the question.

Comment: Then you should be able to do the following without issue: Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\microsoft\sqlserver\computermanagement16" -Query "select * from SqlService"

Comment: Yes, the results are pretty much identical to 2019 (just versions, PIDs and hostname that differ). The returned `__RELPATH`s are `SqlService.ServiceName="MSSQLSERVER",SQLServiceType=1`, `SqlService.ServiceName="SQLBrowser",SQLServiceType=7` and `SqlService.ServiceName="SQLSERVERAGENT",SQLServiceType=2`. I should also mention that other commandlets like `Invoke-SqlCmd` work, it's just enabling HADR that I'm having issue with.

Comment: Do you have any further ideas @SeanGallardy?

Comment: Then the WMI provider isn't the problem. Make sure you're using the latest version of the powershel cmdlets.

Comment: @SeanGallardy I was using the latest released version but I've now fixed it by upgrading to a preview package. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the current pre-release version of the SqlServer PowerShell Module ([22.0.49-preview](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/22.0.49-preview)) fixes the connection issue. It fails with the latest release version ([21.1.18256](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.1.18256)) which was released in July 2021.

Comment: This is because the old versions aren't looking for the new namespace. This is expected, hence why I stated nothing was wrong with the provider and to update whatever powershell cmdlets were being used.